# How do I add the jump function to my script unity

Tags: c#

How do i go about adding the jump function from my spacebar. Currently i have the left and right function working by pressing "d" and "q". I have tried a function that i found online but does not seem to work well.. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_movement : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float sideway_force = 100f;

    float forward_force = 1000f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forward_force * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d")) {
            rb.AddForce(sideway_force * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("q")) {
            rb.AddForce(-sideway_force * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
```

This is the code that i have tried.. :

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 90 * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```